# JWT, OAuth and XSRF on ASP.NET Single Page App - How would I handle the XSRF token expiration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, oauth

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 w/ .NET 4.6, and Identity 2.1.  I'm migrating my app to SPA (Single Page App). I've been investigating the matter, because I got worried about CSRF/XSRF attacks. I have a couple of concerns..

I have started to implement a token-bearer approach using OAuth and JWT through Katana, by following this tutorial: http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/

After implementing it, I realized that I needed to store the JWT in a safe manner. According to the Stack Exchange network and some other websites, the best way to do this is to store it in a Cookie with HTTP flags on. This would prevent the attacker from using a XSS mechanism and steal the token. Unfortunately this approach is susceptible of CSRF attacks, bringing me almost to square 1.

A mechanism suggested by the same sources is to use a Double Cookie implementation. In which I would send both: the CSRF token (random string) and the JWT. Despite that, I'm really worried about generating the CSRF token (which was my main problem). The best way (in my understanding) to retrieve an anti-forgery token is to server-render it

Therefore I get the token through @Html.AntiForgeryToken in my initial load and utilize it for subsequent requests. This creates the following concern: For how long will that token be valid? Or, how would I handle the CSRF token expiration? (Which was my main concern in the beginning)

I don't know how viable would it be to request another CSRF token from the server after the data has been sent. I'm very skeptical on retrieving tokens via AJAX calls...

I haven't found any post so far that dwells this far. So that's why I'm asking.

**Edit**
Giving some thought, I think I could do the following:
Instead of using the JWT as an authentication mechanism. I could use it as an anti-forgery mechanism.

I would use Identity as authentication, and the token would be passed to each request for validation.

If the user is valid and the token is valid, then go ahead.

If the user is valid, and the token invalid, invalidate the request.

If the user is valid, and the token is valid but expired, log out the user.

If the user is invalid, and the token valid, invalidate the token and the request.

Comment: This is plain dumb... The purpose of the JWT is to serve as an unified mechanism for authorization. If I set the expiration date to a reasonable time I can start issuing the user to check on it. So I guess I shall store it in Session Storage and protect myself from XSS attacks.

Comment: And to add a little bit, you can set a hash with the external javascript files, that way if the externa site is compromised the browser will not execute the .js,